# Extjs masking and unmasking in IE and FF

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs, mask

I have a handler, more like a submit button. And I would like to mask the whole page or that form to show wait message until the rest of the process is completed. I did this and it worked in FF but no success in IE, when I do `Ext.getCmp('').body.mask('Loading');` it does nothing, but when I add `.delay(1000)` it shows both in FF and IE and never ends the loading message...

Comment: Is there any error which you are getting in IE? Also, which version of IE and ExtJS you are using?

Comment: 1) you can use the Ext.getBody() to get a ref to the body element. 2) if you show the mask this way you have to manage its display manually, which means you have to show and hide it on the the proper events.

Comment: I decided not to go with masking, now when i do $("#div-id").show(); and hide() and it doesn't work in IE, but in FF it shows and hides divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a note, when using .mask() function, you have to call it to a DOM element, which means you should use it either with

```
Ext.get('yourDomElementId').mask();
```

or

```
Ext.getCmp('yourExtComponentId').el.mask(); //this gets the dom
//element attached to the component
```

I've never used it with .body